# Display SVG from javascript in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

IE 11 is not displaying the image when svg content is loaded through javascript. I think it's due to the onload event not begin triggered, but I can't seem to find out why.

The image is being displayed as expected in Chrome.

```js
$("#btn-generate").on("click", function() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = $("#svg-content").val();
  $("#display").append(img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  IE 11 - issue with displaying SVG content
</h2>
<label for="svg-content">SVG Content</label>
<textarea id="svg-content">data:image/svg+xml,&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&lt;!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd&quot;&gt;&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; version=&quot;1.1&quot; width=&quot;354&quot; height=&quot;84&quot;&gt;&lt;path fill=&quot;none&quot; stroke=&quot;#000000&quot; stroke-width=&quot;2&quot; stroke-linecap=&quot;round&quot; stroke-linejoin=&quot;round&quot; d=&quot;M 5 1 c -0.07 0.66 -3.18 25.7 -4 38 c -0.15 2.28 0.45 4.78 1 7 c 0.42 1.69 1.1 3.5 2 5 c 2.04 3.39 4.44 8.5 7 10 c 2.09 1.23 7.58 1.15 10 0 c 3.59 -1.71 9.33 -6.08 11 -10 c 5.13 -12.04 10.64 -41.19 12 -44 c 0.35 -0.72 3.39 7.34 4 11 c 0.99 5.95 0.36 12.56 1 19 c 0.72 7.18 1.5 16.08 3 21 c 0.32 1.04 2.87 2.27 4 2 c 6.71 -1.62 17.35 -5.39 25 -9 c 3.92 -1.85 8.32 -4.98 11 -8 c 2.2 -2.48 4.01 -6.69 5 -10 c 0.89 -2.98 0.77 -6.6 1 -10 c 0.11 -1.69 0.56 -4.02 0 -5 c -0.5 -0.88 -3.09 -2.23 -4 -2 c -1.16 0.29 -3.69 2.55 -4 4 c -0.81 3.85 -1.51 12.28 0 15 c 1.05 1.89 6.69 2.81 10 3 c 13.63 0.77 28.11 0.29 43 0 c 20.78 -0.4 58.95 -1.96 60 -2 c 0.09 0 -3.8 -0.53 -5 0 c -1.36 0.6 -2.51 3.08 -4 4 c -2.59 1.6 -5.98 2.92 -9 4 c -1.56 0.56 -3.31 0.92 -5 1 c -11.58 0.58 -23.23 1.21 -35 1 c -7.09 -0.13 -13.83 -1.06 -21 -2 c -8.61 -1.12 -19.07 -2.24 -25 -4 c -1.05 -0.31 -2.4 -3.19 -2 -4 c 0.83 -1.67 4.43 -5.34 7 -6 c 11.27 -2.88 26.47 -5.02 40 -6 c 19.07 -1.38 38.72 -1.53 57 -1 c 3.97 0.11 8.83 1.33 12 3 c 2.54 1.34 4.99 4.49 7 7 c 1.91 2.39 3.77 5.24 5 8 c 1.36 3.06 3.6 7.25 3 10 c -1.39 6.37 -7.16 14.78 -10 22 c -0.71 1.82 -1.7 6.13 -1 6 c 4.06 -0.76 21.78 -8.94 33 -12 c 10.72 -2.92 22.83 -3.23 33 -6 c 3.8 -1.04 8.67 -3.86 11 -6 c 0.95 -0.87 1.72 -4.06 1 -5 c -2.6 -3.4 -9.03 -9.3 -14 -12 c -5.97 -3.24 -14.05 -5.93 -21 -7 c -9.74 -1.5 -23.88 -3.59 -31 -1 c -4.91 1.79 -9.34 11.39 -13 17 c -1.08 1.66 -1.57 3.95 -2 6 c -0.9 4.26 -1.66 8.63 -2 13 c -0.33 4.32 0.25 8.81 0 13 c -0.08 1.33 -1.29 4.14 -1 4 c 1.23 -0.57 9.13 -7.49 14 -10 c 5.11 -2.64 11.74 -3.45 17 -6 c 4.86 -2.35 9.09 -6.17 14 -9 c 6.33 -3.65 14.49 -6.84 19 -10 c 0.87 -0.61 1.64 -3.81 1 -4 c -3.89 -1.14 -16.55 -2.89 -25 -3 c -42.31 -0.56 -82.8 0.16 -126 1 c -9.62 0.19 -18.47 1.01 -28 2 c -6.87 0.72 -13.37 1.67 -20 3 c -3.42 0.68 -7.43 1.62 -10 3 c -1.23 0.66 -3.27 3.09 -3 4 c 0.47 1.55 3.91 4.48 6 6 c 1.33 0.97 3.26 1.51 5 2 c 11.39 3.21 22.74 5.7 34 9 c 2.44 0.71 4.72 2.57 7 3 c 2.7 0.51 6.02 0.31 9 0 c 6.71 -0.69 13.25 -1.6 20 -3 c 13.03 -2.7 27.29 -5.51 38 -9 c 1.94 -0.63 3.13 -3.69 5 -5 c 4.62 -3.24 9.77 -6.31 15 -9 c 5.89 -3.03 11.8 -5.63 18 -8 c 5.28 -2.02 10.62 -4.03 16 -5 c 7.41 -1.33 15.57 -0.62 23 -2 c 6.72 -1.25 13.17 -4.61 20 -6 c 11.24 -2.29 22.64 -3.06 34 -5 c 2.41 -0.41 4.71 -1.94 7 -2 c 9.14 -0.25 20.67 0.22 29 1 c 1.04 0.1 2.73 1.18 3 2 c 0.53 1.6 0.75 5.26 0 7 c -0.98 2.3 -3.71 5.11 -6 7 c -5.17 4.27 -11.21 8.69 -17 12 c -3.26 1.86 -7.89 2.34 -11 4 c -1.5 0.8 -2.46 3.49 -4 4 c -6.39 2.13 -15.44 3.65 -23 5 c -1.61 0.29 -3.56 -0.39 -5 0 l -6 3&quot;/&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;</textarea><br />
<input id="btn-generate" type="button" value="Display Image" /><br />
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work also in Firefox - it displays broken image icon. 
UPDATE: In Firefox it doesn't work for [security reasons](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/):

> [...] the following cases will be allowed:
>   [...]
>
> - Opening “data:image/*” in top-level window, **unless it’s “data:image/svg+xml”**

You can create Blob and create URL for it in following manner:

```
var svgcontent = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><some-content /></svg>'
var blob = new Blob([svgcontent], {type: "image/svg+xml"})
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

So you need to extract from your string part that contains `svg` tag with content and MIME type.

Demo (I've removed some tags at the beginning):

```js
$("#btn-generate").on("click", function() {
  var img = new Image();
  var svgcontent = $("#svg-content").val()
  var blob = new Blob([svgcontent], {type: "image/svg+xml"})
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  img.src = url;
  $("#display").append(img);
});
```

```html
<h2>
  IE 11 - issue with displaying SVG content
</h2>
<label for="svg-content">SVG Content</label>
<textarea id="svg-content">&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; version=&quot;1.1&quot; width=&quot;354&quot; height=&quot;84&quot;&gt;&lt;path fill=&quot;none&quot; stroke=&quot;#000000&quot; stroke-width=&quot;2&quot; stroke-linecap=&quot;round&quot; stroke-linejoin=&quot;round&quot; d=&quot;M 5 1 c -0.07 0.66 -3.18 25.7 -4 38 c -0.15 2.28 0.45 4.78 1 7 c 0.42 1.69 1.1 3.5 2 5 c 2.04 3.39 4.44 8.5 7 10 c 2.09 1.23 7.58 1.15 10 0 c 3.59 -1.71 9.33 -6.08 11 -10 c 5.13 -12.04 10.64 -41.19 12 -44 c 0.35 -0.72 3.39 7.34 4 11 c 0.99 5.95 0.36 12.56 1 19 c 0.72 7.18 1.5 16.08 3 21 c 0.32 1.04 2.87 2.27 4 2 c 6.71 -1.62 17.35 -5.39 25 -9 c 3.92 -1.85 8.32 -4.98 11 -8 c 2.2 -2.48 4.01 -6.69 5 -10 c 0.89 -2.98 0.77 -6.6 1 -10 c 0.11 -1.69 0.56 -4.02 0 -5 c -0.5 -0.88 -3.09 -2.23 -4 -2 c -1.16 0.29 -3.69 2.55 -4 4 c -0.81 3.85 -1.51 12.28 0 15 c 1.05 1.89 6.69 2.81 10 3 c 13.63 0.77 28.11 0.29 43 0 c 20.78 -0.4 58.95 -1.96 60 -2 c 0.09 0 -3.8 -0.53 -5 0 c -1.36 0.6 -2.51 3.08 -4 4 c -2.59 1.6 -5.98 2.92 -9 4 c -1.56 0.56 -3.31 0.92 -5 1 c -11.58 0.58 -23.23 1.21 -35 1 c -7.09 -0.13 -13.83 -1.06 -21 -2 c -8.61 -1.12 -19.07 -2.24 -25 -4 c -1.05 -0.31 -2.4 -3.19 -2 -4 c 0.83 -1.67 4.43 -5.34 7 -6 c 11.27 -2.88 26.47 -5.02 40 -6 c 19.07 -1.38 38.72 -1.53 57 -1 c 3.97 0.11 8.83 1.33 12 3 c 2.54 1.34 4.99 4.49 7 7 c 1.91 2.39 3.77 5.24 5 8 c 1.36 3.06 3.6 7.25 3 10 c -1.39 6.37 -7.16 14.78 -10 22 c -0.71 1.82 -1.7 6.13 -1 6 c 4.06 -0.76 21.78 -8.94 33 -12 c 10.72 -2.92 22.83 -3.23 33 -6 c 3.8 -1.04 8.67 -3.86 11 -6 c 0.95 -0.87 1.72 -4.06 1 -5 c -2.6 -3.4 -9.03 -9.3 -14 -12 c -5.97 -3.24 -14.05 -5.93 -21 -7 c -9.74 -1.5 -23.88 -3.59 -31 -1 c -4.91 1.79 -9.34 11.39 -13 17 c -1.08 1.66 -1.57 3.95 -2 6 c -0.9 4.26 -1.66 8.63 -2 13 c -0.33 4.32 0.25 8.81 0 13 c -0.08 1.33 -1.29 4.14 -1 4 c 1.23 -0.57 9.13 -7.49 14 -10 c 5.11 -2.64 11.74 -3.45 17 -6 c 4.86 -2.35 9.09 -6.17 14 -9 c 6.33 -3.65 14.49 -6.84 19 -10 c 0.87 -0.61 1.64 -3.81 1 -4 c -3.89 -1.14 -16.55 -2.89 -25 -3 c -42.31 -0.56 -82.8 0.16 -126 1 c -9.62 0.19 -18.47 1.01 -28 2 c -6.87 0.72 -13.37 1.67 -20 3 c -3.42 0.68 -7.43 1.62 -10 3 c -1.23 0.66 -3.27 3.09 -3 4 c 0.47 1.55 3.91 4.48 6 6 c 1.33 0.97 3.26 1.51 5 2 c 11.39 3.21 22.74 5.7 34 9 c 2.44 0.71 4.72 2.57 7 3 c 2.7 0.51 6.02 0.31 9 0 c 6.71 -0.69 13.25 -1.6 20 -3 c 13.03 -2.7 27.29 -5.51 38 -9 c 1.94 -0.63 3.13 -3.69 5 -5 c 4.62 -3.24 9.77 -6.31 15 -9 c 5.89 -3.03 11.8 -5.63 18 -8 c 5.28 -2.02 10.62 -4.03 16 -5 c 7.41 -1.33 15.57 -0.62 23 -2 c 6.72 -1.25 13.17 -4.61 20 -6 c 11.24 -2.29 22.64 -3.06 34 -5 c 2.41 -0.41 4.71 -1.94 7 -2 c 9.14 -0.25 20.67 0.22 29 1 c 1.04 0.1 2.73 1.18 3 2 c 0.53 1.6 0.75 5.26 0 7 c -0.98 2.3 -3.71 5.11 -6 7 c -5.17 4.27 -11.21 8.69 -17 12 c -3.26 1.86 -7.89 2.34 -11 4 c -1.5 0.8 -2.46 3.49 -4 4 c -6.39 2.13 -15.44 3.65 -23 5 c -1.61 0.29 -3.56 -0.39 -5 0 l -6 3&quot;/&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;</textarea><br />
<input id="btn-generate" type="button" value="Display Image" /><br />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Looking at the question, OP *is giving it a URL* (a `data:` one).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so both IE and Firefox seem to don't recognize it as URL. Maybe it's matter of [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this also worked.

```js
$("#btn-generate").on("click", function() {

    $("#display").replaceWith( $('<div/>').append($("#svg-content").val()).find('svg:first').attr('id','display') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  IE 11 - issue with displaying SVG content
</h2>
<label for="svg-content">SVG Content</label>
<textarea id="svg-content">data:image/svg+xml,&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&lt;!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd&quot;&gt;&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; version=&quot;1.1&quot; width=&quot;354&quot; height=&quot;84&quot;&gt;&lt;path fill=&quot;none&quot; stroke=&quot;#000000&quot; stroke-width=&quot;2&quot; stroke-linecap=&quot;round&quot; stroke-linejoin=&quot;round&quot; d=&quot;M 5 1 c -0.07 0.66 -3.18 25.7 -4 38 c -0.15 2.28 0.45 4.78 1 7 c 0.42 1.69 1.1 3.5 2 5 c 2.04 3.39 4.44 8.5 7 10 c 2.09 1.23 7.58 1.15 10 0 c 3.59 -1.71 9.33 -6.08 11 -10 c 5.13 -12.04 10.64 -41.19 12 -44 c 0.35 -0.72 3.39 7.34 4 11 c 0.99 5.95 0.36 12.56 1 19 c 0.72 7.18 1.5 16.08 3 21 c 0.32 1.04 2.87 2.27 4 2 c 6.71 -1.62 17.35 -5.39 25 -9 c 3.92 -1.85 8.32 -4.98 11 -8 c 2.2 -2.48 4.01 -6.69 5 -10 c 0.89 -2.98 0.77 -6.6 1 -10 c 0.11 -1.69 0.56 -4.02 0 -5 c -0.5 -0.88 -3.09 -2.23 -4 -2 c -1.16 0.29 -3.69 2.55 -4 4 c -0.81 3.85 -1.51 12.28 0 15 c 1.05 1.89 6.69 2.81 10 3 c 13.63 0.77 28.11 0.29 43 0 c 20.78 -0.4 58.95 -1.96 60 -2 c 0.09 0 -3.8 -0.53 -5 0 c -1.36 0.6 -2.51 3.08 -4 4 c -2.59 1.6 -5.98 2.92 -9 4 c -1.56 0.56 -3.31 0.92 -5 1 c -11.58 0.58 -23.23 1.21 -35 1 c -7.09 -0.13 -13.83 -1.06 -21 -2 c -8.61 -1.12 -19.07 -2.24 -25 -4 c -1.05 -0.31 -2.4 -3.19 -2 -4 c 0.83 -1.67 4.43 -5.34 7 -6 c 11.27 -2.88 26.47 -5.02 40 -6 c 19.07 -1.38 38.72 -1.53 57 -1 c 3.97 0.11 8.83 1.33 12 3 c 2.54 1.34 4.99 4.49 7 7 c 1.91 2.39 3.77 5.24 5 8 c 1.36 3.06 3.6 7.25 3 10 c -1.39 6.37 -7.16 14.78 -10 22 c -0.71 1.82 -1.7 6.13 -1 6 c 4.06 -0.76 21.78 -8.94 33 -12 c 10.72 -2.92 22.83 -3.23 33 -6 c 3.8 -1.04 8.67 -3.86 11 -6 c 0.95 -0.87 1.72 -4.06 1 -5 c -2.6 -3.4 -9.03 -9.3 -14 -12 c -5.97 -3.24 -14.05 -5.93 -21 -7 c -9.74 -1.5 -23.88 -3.59 -31 -1 c -4.91 1.79 -9.34 11.39 -13 17 c -1.08 1.66 -1.57 3.95 -2 6 c -0.9 4.26 -1.66 8.63 -2 13 c -0.33 4.32 0.25 8.81 0 13 c -0.08 1.33 -1.29 4.14 -1 4 c 1.23 -0.57 9.13 -7.49 14 -10 c 5.11 -2.64 11.74 -3.45 17 -6 c 4.86 -2.35 9.09 -6.17 14 -9 c 6.33 -3.65 14.49 -6.84 19 -10 c 0.87 -0.61 1.64 -3.81 1 -4 c -3.89 -1.14 -16.55 -2.89 -25 -3 c -42.31 -0.56 -82.8 0.16 -126 1 c -9.62 0.19 -18.47 1.01 -28 2 c -6.87 0.72 -13.37 1.67 -20 3 c -3.42 0.68 -7.43 1.62 -10 3 c -1.23 0.66 -3.27 3.09 -3 4 c 0.47 1.55 3.91 4.48 6 6 c 1.33 0.97 3.26 1.51 5 2 c 11.39 3.21 22.74 5.7 34 9 c 2.44 0.71 4.72 2.57 7 3 c 2.7 0.51 6.02 0.31 9 0 c 6.71 -0.69 13.25 -1.6 20 -3 c 13.03 -2.7 27.29 -5.51 38 -9 c 1.94 -0.63 3.13 -3.69 5 -5 c 4.62 -3.24 9.77 -6.31 15 -9 c 5.89 -3.03 11.8 -5.63 18 -8 c 5.28 -2.02 10.62 -4.03 16 -5 c 7.41 -1.33 15.57 -0.62 23 -2 c 6.72 -1.25 13.17 -4.61 20 -6 c 11.24 -2.29 22.64 -3.06 34 -5 c 2.41 -0.41 4.71 -1.94 7 -2 c 9.14 -0.25 20.67 0.22 29 1 c 1.04 0.1 2.73 1.18 3 2 c 0.53 1.6 0.75 5.26 0 7 c -0.98 2.3 -3.71 5.11 -6 7 c -5.17 4.27 -11.21 8.69 -17 12 c -3.26 1.86 -7.89 2.34 -11 4 c -1.5 0.8 -2.46 3.49 -4 4 c -6.39 2.13 -15.44 3.65 -23 5 c -1.61 0.29 -3.56 -0.39 -5 0 l -6 3&quot;/&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;</textarea><br />
<input id="btn-generate" type="button" value="Display Image" /><br />
<svg id="display"></svg>
```